# Select between two date-columns with interval

Tags: mysql, datetime, intervals

I have a table with a column for a start datetime and a end datetime and a column (quantity) with a number. For a display of a diagram, I need a query that outputs the added values from the column "quantity" in intervals of 15 minutes with given a start and end datetime.

Currently, I am solving this through a loop in PHP, creating 96 queries for a day. Very bad, I know.

The table looks like this, for example:

```
id      from_datetime           until_datetime          quantity
----------------------------------------------------------------
1       2018-10-30 08:00:00     2018-10-30 09:59:59     5
2       2018-10-30 09:00:00     2018-10-30 10:59:59     1
3       2018-10-30 10:30:00     2018-10-30 11:59:59     3
4       2018-10-30 10:30:00     2018-10-30 14:59:59     3
5       2018-10-30 11:00:00     2018-10-30 13:59:59     2
```

The result with given 2018-10-30 06:00:00 as start-datetime and 2018-10-30 16:00:00 should be the following:
Timestamps without any results should be a line with zero as number.

```
timestamp               result  
------------------------------
2018-10-30 06:00:00     0        
2018-10-30 06:15:00     0        
2018-10-30 06:30:00     0        
2018-10-30 06:45:00     0        
2018-10-30 07:00:00     0        
2018-10-30 07:15:00     0        
2018-10-30 07:30:00     0        
2018-10-30 07:45:00     0        
2018-10-30 08:00:00     5        
2018-10-30 08:15:00     5        
2018-10-30 08:30:00     5        
2018-10-30 08:45:00     5        
2018-10-30 09:00:00     6        
2018-10-30 09:15:00     6        
2018-10-30 09:30:00     6        
2018-10-30 09:45:00     6        
2018-10-30 10:00:00     1        
2018-10-30 10:15:00     1        
2018-10-30 10:30:00     7        
2018-10-30 10:45:00     7        
2018-10-30 11:00:00     8        
2018-10-30 11:15:00     8        
2018-10-30 11:30:00     8        
2018-10-30 11:45:00     8        
2018-10-30 12:00:00     5        
2018-10-30 12:15:00     5        
2018-10-30 12:30:00     5        
2018-10-30 12:45:00     5        
2018-10-30 13:00:00     5        
2018-10-30 13:15:00     5        
2018-10-30 13:30:00     5        
2018-10-30 13:45:00     5        
2018-10-30 14:00:00     3        
2018-10-30 14:15:00     3        
2018-10-30 14:30:00     3        
2018-10-30 14:45:00     3        
2018-10-30 15:00:00     0        
2018-10-30 15:15:00     0        
2018-10-30 15:30:00     0        
2018-10-30 15:45:00     0        
2018-10-30 16:00:00     0
```

My PHP-solution works but is very hungry and slow. certainly this can be solved with a single query, but I failed with many attempts.

Cheers,
Eric

My php is a simple loop with php DateTime object:

```
$begin = new DateTime("2018-10-30 06:00:00"); 
$end = new DateTime("2018-10-30 16:00:00");
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('15 minutes');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach ( $period as $dt ) {
    $check_from = new DateTime($dt->format("Y-m-d H:i"));
    $check_until = new Datetime($dt->format("Y-m-d H:i"));

    // MySql-Query and write Array with the data
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a php loop per se - it's just the 96 queries bit that seems a bit, well, loopy.

Comment: Why cant you get all the data at once in a single query, and then use loop and array tricks to display the data.

Comment: if you don't want to go into complicated full SQL solution, you can still do your loop in PHP and construct a single query based on the concatenation of your multiple `select` instead of querying each loop turn (by the way, it would be nice if you showed us the PHP code in question)

Comment: Updated with the PHP code...